# Eclipse debugging: Variable names are not showing, but values are showing

Tags: java, eclipse

I didn't remember how I get to this stage, but now when I open my debugging perspective, the Variables view will not show "Name", it only shows "Value". I've tried resetting the perspective, but it didn't work.

My Eclipse (Java) version is **Mars 4.5.0**;
I am running it on **Ubuntu 14.04**

Below is the situation:

[image]

Help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just found a way to make the Name column visible.

Click on the upside down triangle button at the upper right corner -> Layout -> Select Columns...

[image]

Check the box of Name column. This would make your Name column visible.

[image]

Comment: I already have the 'Name' selected, but when I deselect all, the variable name showed up. This solved my problem.

Comment: In my case it was also selected. Deselecting and clicking "OK", followed by opening the dialog again, selecting and clicking "OK" worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might've dragged the "Value" column all the way to the left, hiding the "Name" column by accident. Try having your mouse pointed at the left-edge of the "Value" column and drag it to the right again.

Comment: This is an intuitive thinking. I tried, but not work...I will only be able to drag the bar between Debug and Variable

Comment: It's the difference between a few pixels. If you go a little too far to the left, it it'll drag the entire perspective. When I purposely dragged my "Value" column all the way to the left, it looked exactly like yours. I had to try it a couple times to figure it out.

Comment: But if that's not the case, I'll keep looking into it.

Comment: Try moving your mouse to the point where it'll be dragging the Perspectives. But slowly move towards the right until the mouse changes from "<->" to a pointer. And keep shifting to the right until it changes again to "<->".

Comment: Thank you very much. Yet I haven't been able to succeed. I will try a couple more times

Comment: Sorry about that, hope you figure it out soon.